# how to show qDebug in library in to text file

Tags: c++, qt

I writing program using dynamic library qt. In main program im using  **qInstallMsgHandler** to print all qDebug to text file. but not working with my lib, qDebug in my lib not print to text file ,that print to console views. how can i write all qDebug in library to text file.
this is my lib fuction call mylib.so

```
QString leave_public::execute(QString data_json_string) {
QString command=data_json_string+"1120";
qDebug()<<command excute<<command;
return command;
}
```

and it is main fuction

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>

void customMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const char *msg) {
QString dt = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 

QString txt = QString("[%1] ").arg(dt);

switch (type) {
case QtDebugMsg:
    txt += QString("{Debug} \t %1").arg(msg);
    break;
case QtWarningMsg:
    txt += QString("{Warning}  %1").arg(msg);
    break;}

 QFile outFile("LogFile.log");
   outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);

   QTextStream textStream(&outFile);
   textStream << txt << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {       
    qDebug<<"string in Main";
    qInstallMsgHandler(customMessageHandler);
    mylib=newfucnlib;
    QString command_main=newfuclib.execute("json-string-input");
return 0;
}
```

command_main return value but qDebug in mylib.so not print into text file. anyone can help me how to print qDebug in mylib to text file. thanks all

Comment: why don't you try `fstream`?

Comment: im try but not working. @Michael could you give me suggest where im put **fstream**. thanks

Comment: `fstream` is a library that allows you to operate on files, you could use it instead of QFile. Example Code: `std::fstream fs;` `fs.open("text.txt");` `fs << "Write something to text.txt";` `fs.close();`. There's a lot of documentation about `fstream` out there, which can help you more than me with this narrow space in comments.

Comment: thanks @Michaek, im try your suggest and it ok but i only write qDebug in main fuction not prin qDebug in mylib.. how can i write also qDebug in mylib